# JavaScript Scrollbar Plugin recognizing manipulation on orginal element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, scrollbar

I'm searching for a jQuery plugin which adds custom scrollbars to a div. I know, there are tons of plugins like this out there and i tried about 10 of them now with no success because i need a plugin with some very special features and i was wondering if anyone knows one which comes near.

1. Its very important that the plugin does not poll for changes of its content (setInterval) or that it can at least be disabled.
2. It must be possible to tell the plugin to update itsself manually when i know that its contents has been changed
3. The most important thing (which seems to be the thing that is missing on most plugins): the original element reference must be kept.

So if i do:

```
$("#myElement").coolScrollbarPlugin();
$("#myElement").append("<h1>New Content</h1>");
$("#myElement").coolScrollbarPlugin("update");
```

the plugin needs to recognize this. In the best case, the plugin takes the jquery element i applied the plugin on as its content pane to recognize any manipulation done on the element.

What i can't do:

```
$("#myElement").coolScrollbarPlugin();
$("#myElement").coolScrollbarPlugin("getConentElement").append("<h1>New Content</h1>");
$("#myElement").coolScrollbarPlugin("update");
```

This limitation is due to the surrounding application framework which will do manipulations on the scrollable elements that i'm not able to affect.

- Are there any plugins that you know matching all this criteria?
- Are there other ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: Are you still interested in solution?

Comment: Absolutely still found no appropriate solution. We decided to stay with native scrollbars for now (looking different in different browsers).

Answer (score 0):

If you get scrollable element by id or assign element to variable before applying scrollbar, you can try [jQuery Scrollbar](https://github.com/gromo/jquery.scrollbar/). The only change that is made - element is wrapped into another element with the same classes (to apply CSS styles of source element's height/width & design for scrollbar).

You can disable content/container size cheking using option `autoUpdate:false` and call `init` function to recalculate scrollbar sizes after update.